# ggplot2: How to dynamically wrap/resize/rescale x axis labels so they won't overlap

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, ggtext

I'm trying to achieve a solution for wrapping x axis labels so they won't overlap. I know this question has been asked several times, and that there are [some good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41607201/6105259). However, no solution that I've seen answers how to re-wrap the labels as the plot gets *resized*.

Three different answers at SO make me believe this could be attainable.

1. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36319229/ggplot2-geom-text-resize-with-the-plot-and-force-fit-text-within-geom-bar/36327897#36327897) wrote a custom-made `geom` for fitting the *bar*'s label `size` to fit within the bar's width, dynamically as you resize the plot.
2. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65444374/6105259) relies on an *extension* package for `ggplot2` called [`ggtext`](https://wilkelab.org/ggtext/articles/plotting_text.html). The solution allows dynamic word wrapping of the plot's *title*, as you resize the plot, based on creating a [`element_textbox()`](https://wilkelab.org/ggtext/#markdown-in-theme-elements).
3. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65943667/6105259) relies on another extension called [`ggfittext`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggfittext/vignettes/introduction-to-ggfittext.html). It shows how the `size` of the label inside the bar can vary dynamically to fit the bar's dimensions as you resize the plot. Essentially, it addresses the same problem as solution (1) above, but is much more powerful. In fact, and this is the feature that makes me hopeful, it relies on a general solution `geom_fit_text()` to fit text inside rectangles, not just `geom_bar()`s.

### Some demo data to work with

**1. Just to show the typical output when x axis labels are overlapping**

```r
  library(tidyverse)
  
  my_mtcars <-
    mtcars[15:20,] %>% 
    rownames_to_column("cars")
  
  my_mtcars %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = cars, y = mpg, fill = cars)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

---

**2. When we use `ggfittext` we can see how labels inside the bars shrink in size to fit the bar**

```r
  library(tidyverse)
  library(ggfittext)
#> Warning: package 'ggfittext' was built under R version 4.0.3
  
  my_mtcars <-
    mtcars[15:20,] %>% 
    rownames_to_column("cars")
  
  my_mtcars %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = cars, y = mpg, fill = cars)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    geom_bar_text(aes(label = cars), 
      color = "blue", 
      vjust = 1, 
      size = 7 * ggplot2::.pt, 
      min.size = 0,
      padding.x = grid::unit(0, "pt"),
      padding.y = grid::unit(0, "pt"))
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: label
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

---

**3. `ggfittext` has the `reflow` argument that promotes text wrapping**

```r
  library(tidyverse)
  library(ggfittext)
#> Warning: package 'ggfittext' was built under R version 4.0.3
  
  my_mtcars <-
    mtcars[15:20,] %>% 
    rownames_to_column("cars")
  
  my_mtcars %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = cars, y = mpg, fill = cars)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    geom_bar_text(aes(label = cars), 
      color = "blue", 
      vjust = 1, 
      size = 7 * ggplot2::.pt, 
      min.size = 0,
      padding.x = grid::unit(0, "pt"),
      padding.y = grid::unit(0, "pt"),
      reflow = TRUE ## <--------------- added this
      )
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: label
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

---

#### My question

I don't know how to do it, but could we get x axis labels wrapped/resized/rescaled dynamically, by somehow letting `ggfittext` do the hard work for us? In the naïve way I see this, the text within the bars is already rendered the right way, can we just "copy" this rendering somehow to the axis labels?

Comment: Perhaps relevant issue on ggfittext's github: https://github.com/wilkox/ggfittext/issues/14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about we just place the `ggfittext` text below the y-axis? We turn off clipping and set the `oob` and `limits` to suit our data. Should probably tweak the `axis.text.x` size to align better with the x-axis title.

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 4.0.3
#> Warning: package 'readr' was built under R version 4.0.3
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 4.0.3
library(ggfittext)
#> Warning: package 'ggfittext' was built under R version 4.0.3

my_mtcars <-
  mtcars[15:20,] %>% 
  rownames_to_column("cars")

my_mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = cars, y = mpg, fill = cars)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_fit_text(aes(label = cars, y = -4),
                reflow = TRUE, height = 50,
                show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(oob = scales::oob_keep,
                     limits = c(0, NA)) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "transparent", size = 18))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

EDIT: Getting the labels out of the grob

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggfittext)

my_mtcars <-
  mtcars[15:20,] %>% 
  rownames_to_column("cars")

p <- my_mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = cars, y = mpg, fill = cars)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_fit_text(aes(label = cars, y = -1),
                reflow = TRUE, height = 50,
                show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(oob = scales::oob_keep,
                     limits = c(0, NA)) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "transparent", size = 18))

grob <- grid::makeContent(layer_grob(p, 2)[[1]])$children

sizes <- vapply(grob, function(x){x$gp$fontsize}, numeric(1))
labels <- unname(vapply(grob, function(x){x$label}, character(1)))
print(labels)
#> [1] "Cadillac\nFleetwood"  "Lincoln\nContinental" "Chrysler\nImperial"  
#> [4] "Fiat 128"             "Honda Civic"          "Toyota\nCorolla"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is really good, thank you. However, `y = -4` suggests a limitation. While `-4` works for this plot, a different plot could have any y-scale, and `-4` won't work. Is there a way to set the vertical placement independently of the y values?

Comment: I have another idea.... is it possible at all to hack the rendered labels, and extract both the word wrapping (e.g., `"Fiat 128"`, `"Honda\nCivic"`) *and* text size, then pass that to `scale_x_discrete()`?

Comment: Yes I agree that this is a limitation of this approach, which is why I've left some suggestions for the ggtfittext authors on their github to implement it at the `theme()` level.

Comment: I like the idea, but the limitation is that the ggfittext isn't rendered until actual render time and all absolute dimensions are known. You'd have to somehow intercept their `makeContent.fittexttree` method, which you can do with the debugger, but this is even less generalisable than manually setting a `y` position. Also, if you resize the device window, the values you've intercepted aren't the correct ones anymore.

Comment: Can't we first save the rendered plot to object `p`, then extract the info from `p` and add `scale_x_discrete()`? And finally wrap it all in one function... It will be a semi-dynamic solution, but sufficient.

Comment: I don't think `scale_x_discrete()` does different sizes for labels, but you could get the text wrapped part. And I don't think you can rely on the vectorisation of theme elements that you can transfer that via `theme(axis.text.x = ...)`.

Comment: Then we can give the smallest size (meaning, the smallest rendered by `ggfittext`) to all labels. It will actually look better than varying sizes.

Comment: I'm looking through `grob <- grid::makeContent(layer_grob(p, 2))$children`, wherein `p` is the plot object, but I cannot find varying sizes. You can find the wrapped text by `labels <- vapply(grob, function(x){x$label}, character(1))` though.

Comment: I got `NULL` returned for `grob`. Could you do a `reprex()` maybe?

Comment: Ah yes I forgot to subset the layer_grob, see edit.

Comment: Well if it just is about having wrapped text, you could try `stringr::str_wrap()` instead, that seems a lot easier than delving into the graphics devices.

Comment: Sure it is much simpler, but how could I fit the `width` of `str_wrap()`, which is defined as # of characters, with the changing width of bars? The number of characters that fit a given bar width is a matter of font size. I don't know how to calculate this, and especially given the fact that bars width changes from one plot to another, as data changes. Also consider situations where you might want to use `facet_grid()` etc. That's why I wanted to rely on some other function to do the dirty work... `ggfittext` seemed good for the task

Comment: Yes I agree that their algorithm is good. If I can find the time tomorrow I could maybe try to get an `element_fittext()` working.

Comment: Disappointingly, I couldn't get it to work properly. It'll likely require changes on ggfittext's side.

Comment: Thanks for trying! Would you mind trying to update your answer with a workflow for (1) getting the text correctly wrapped (using `ggfittext`), (2) saving to `p`, (3) extracting the info from the grob, (4) re-plotting with labels through `scale_x_discrete()` *but without* the `ggfittext` labels elsewhere? I wonder how generalizable/solid we can make such method. Problem is that I tried hacking the grob myself and couldn't figure out what's going on there.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer and post another question regarding how to extract the labels and their size and re-plot, in a generalizable way.

Answer (score -1):

How about just changing the angle or size of the text?

angle:

```
my_mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = cars, y = mpg, fill = cars)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

size:

```
my_mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = cars, y = mpg, fill = cars)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 4))
```

Comment: Of course we could, and I'm aware of such solutions. I acknowledged that by referencing to this [rundown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41568411/how-to-maintain-size-of-ggplot-with-long-labels/41607201#41607201) at the very beginning of this post. But my question is different.

Comment: Ah, apologies, I didn't go into the references.