# automatically assign width for stringr::str_wrap using base_height in cowplot::save_plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, stringr, cowplot

I want to automatically assign the `width` value for `str_wrap` so that the text fits the width of the plot, when I know the `base_height` I want to use in `save_plot`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
library(stringr)
caption_text <- c("this is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long caption text")
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, colour = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold", colour = "black"),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold", colour = "black")) + 
  labs(x = "Length", y = "Width",
       caption = str_wrap(caption_text, width = 120))
p
save_plot("figures/pic.png",
          p,
          base_height = 8
          )
```

[image]

(text doesnt fit the width of the plot)

What I want to be able to do is automate it like so:

```
my_base_height = 8
str_wrap_width = my_base_height*SOME_VALUE
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, colour = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold", colour = "black"),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold", colour = "black")) + 
  labs(x = "Length", y = "Width",
       caption = str_wrap(caption_text, str_wrap_width))
p
save_plot("figures/pic.png",
          p,
          base_height = my_base_height
)
```

but I dont know how to extract the width of a plot produced from `cowplot` with a known `base_height` value (inches) so that it can be supplied to `str_wrap`.

Any ideas?
thanks

Comment: Would this work for you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/65444374/646761 ?

Comment: unfortunately not, it doesn't answer my question and is not automated. thanks though

Comment: You could try `str_wrap_width = my_base_height * (2 * dev.size()[1])` - you might need to adjust the 2 a bit higher or lower depending on your default sizes.

Comment: @AndrewGustar thanks! that seems to work but it took me awhile to get consistent output. I played around with the `2` until I got it working but when I then applied it to my real data it wasn't working - turned out that I was adding `theme_cowplot()` which was naturally changing the font size, distorting the plot. I also realised that you need to work out a separate value (from the `2`) if you are plotting a different type of figure (e.g., `facet_wrap)` but the good thing is that that value then seems to work for all `facet_wrap` plots irrespective of the number of `rows` and `cols`. Cheers